# Creating classes 'back' from WSDL

Tags: c#, wsdl

I've got some WSDL description of a protocol which I need to implement (-> client 'knows' the API, I need just to write server for it). Is there any tool for c# that will generate some starting classes for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - check out [`svcutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) .

From MSDN:

> The ServiceModel Metadata Utility tool
>   is used to generate service model code
>   from metadata documents and metadata
>   documents from service model code.
>
> The ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool
>   can be found at the Windows SDK
>   installation location, specifically,
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin

`svcutil.exe` is the WCF-related tool for this job - with WCF being available in .NET 3.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started using [WSCF Blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/) which generates WSDL files from xsd and service and data objects from a WSDL.  It's pretty good.

Comment: the OP is trying to create C# code from an existing WSDL - kinda the opposite of what WSCF Blue does, no??

Answer (score 0):

wsdl.exe is a standard utility to work with wsdl services.
Here is a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(VS.80).aspx