# Generating C#.net class from WSDL file

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl

I want to generate Web Service Classes (c#.net) from WSDL File. I want server side code not client side. Is there any tool or any other way available that can generate WCF service code from WSDL file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating classes 'back' from WSDL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676663/creating-classes-back-from-wsdl)

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Visual Studio you can run SvcUtil.exe at the command prompt this will generate all of the C# objects based on the types defined in the WSDL, plus a service proxy that will expose the service as C# methods. It will also provide you with a sample config file for the WCF bindings. This is the same tool that Visual Studio uses for its Add Server Reference wizard, so either solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

try http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/. this will generate WSDL based on XSD and generate code from wsdl.